# I have routing problem with Axios and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, axios

I'm trying to make a simple ajax request with Rails and Axios, but its seems that I have a routing problem

My Ajax request is make with POST method

```
axios.post('/post', {
                        title: title,
                        pseudo: pseudo,
                        text: text,
                        topic: topic
                    })
                    .then(res => console.log(res))
                    .catch(e => console.log(e))

             }
```

My controller have `respond_to`

```
respond_to do |format|
       format.json { render json: {result: 'ok'} }
end
```

But Rails processed with the wrong controller and the wrong method, I expected `Processing by PostController#create as JSON` not `Processing by MainController#default as HTML`

```
Started GET "/post?title=&text=++++++++++++&pseudo=" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-03-16 12:29:23 +0100
Processing by MainController#default as HTML
  Parameters: {"title"=>"", "text"=>"            ", "pseudo"=>"", "topic"=>""}
  Rendering main/default.html.erb within layouts/application
  Post Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (topic = '') ORDER BY "posts"."updated_at" DESC LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2  [["LIMIT", 12], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  ↳ app/views/main/default.html.erb:40
  Rendered main/default.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 11.2ms | Allocations: 1178)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
Completed 200 OK in 192ms (Views: 188.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms | Allocations: 11445)
```

Here my rails routes

```
 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                               Controller#Action
                                      GET    /                                                                                        main#default
                                      GET    /:topic(.:format)                                                                      main#default
                    comment_index POST   /comment(.:format)                                                                   comment#create
                      new_comment GET    /comment/new(.:format)                                                               comment#new
                          comment GET    /comment/:id(.:format)                                                               comment#show
                           post_index POST   /post(.:format)                                                                          post#create
                             new_post GET    /post/new(.:format)                                                                      post#new
                                      GET    /:topic/:post(.:format)                                                                post#show
```

Comment: Try `axios.post('/post.json'...)`

Comment: @razvans same result, but when I execute the 'axios code' directly in the web console of navigator it's working

Comment: I'm also using Vue.js I think the problem come from there

Comment: Please update with the request headers Do a 'raise request.headers.inspect' in your controller action.